# Explicit intent working single time in a loop

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to run an explicit intent to set multiple alarms at different times.

I am trying to do this from a CustomAdapter.

I have an onclicklister on a button . The alarm is getting set for only the first value in ArrayList . Then even though the loop is running for all the elements of arraylist .
The alarms are not added .

Here is my button on click method

```
currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.alarm_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    MedicineRecordHandler mrd=arrayList.get(position);
                    for(String i:mrd.getReminder()){
                        int hour=Integer.parseInt(i.substring(0,2));
                        int min=Integer.parseInt(i.substring(2,4));
                        createAlarm(mrd.getName(),hour,min);
                    }

                }
            });
```

In the above code `mrd.getReminder()` returns a String type arrayList containing times like [ "0800" , "1400","2030" ]

and here is my create alarm method

```
public void createAlarm(String message, int hour, int minutes) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minutes)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```